# How does JDK 7 implement NIO2 on Linux?

Tags: linux, java-7, nio2

I know that the JDK 7 implements NIO2 on Windows using IOCP, but how about Linux?

Although Linux has AIO since 2.6, it's only useful on files. What about the network part?